# Converting a string to an integer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is for a project and this is only a single piece of the entire program that I'm hung up on.

I am being given a file where the format of the information is:

> 200707211245 F70.5

The numbers before the space are the `YYYYMMDDTTTT` `T=time` and I have to output to a new file in the format:

> 21.38 C  ---  recorded on 07/21/2007 at 12:45

This is fairly straight forward process, but I can't figure out how to change the first 7 numbers into an integer that I can pass to a function to format the date and time correctly. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Subsequently this is all I've been able to do. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. I'm getting an error over the `.c_str()` portion of the code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open("inputData.txt", ios::in);

  ofstream oFile;
  oFile.open("results.dat", ios::out);

  int date = atoi(inFile.c_str());

  return 0;
}

int getDate(int date)
{
}
```

Comment: you should first read the value, example: `std::string date_str; inFile >> date_str;` (this would read until the space) and convert the `string` data to `int` (all or a substring).

Comment: Please note that to achieve your goal, you don't really need to convert anything to int, all you gotta do is read the input and write into the output, changing the format.

Comment: The information comes to me as a string from the file, or so I thought anyway. There is also going to be more than the single line of information. So I need to be able to put it in a function that will repeat the process over and over for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

First some notes:

- `atoi` return and `int` value, your number `200707211245` have 12 digits (int range is `–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`, ***ten digits max***), your number don't fit in the type range, you would obtain strange results.
- Better to use [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/libs/lexical_cast/) from `boost`

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

int get_date(long long date) {
    std::cout << date << std::endl;
    return date;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in_file("H:\\save.txt", ios::in);
    if (!in_file.is_open())
        return -1;

    std::string date_str;
    in_file >> date_str;

    int date1 = atoi(date_str.c_str()); // would overflow
    long long date2 = boost::lexical_cast<long long>(date_str);

    get_date(date2);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
200707211245
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this problem is to parse the string input into separate strings for Y, M, D, H, M and temp. Read a line of input and divide it into pieces. You probably don't want to use Boost for a class. Just use std::string and the string operations in the standard library.

Then you can convert those little strings into little integers if you like, or just reformat them blindly into the output.

The temperature string will have to be converted to double in order to convert to Celsius.